# SQL server [Join Query + Multiple Condition]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL server 2008

Hello

here is my query which returns the result

```
SELECT * FROM Rooms
WHERE RoomID in 
(SELECT t1.RoomId FROM 
(Rooms t1 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT RoomID, SUM(quantity) AS QTY FROM Room_Item GROUP BY RoomID
HAVING SUM(Quantity) = 0) t2 ON t1.RoomID = t2.RoomID))
```

above written query will return me the roomid of the rooms which dosen't have any items in it (quantity = 0),
but now i want to filter out the result by buildings,

i got the list of room for specific building as below

```
select roomid from rooms where buildingblockid in (select buidingblockid from buildingblock where buildigID = 1)
```

so my query will be

return the roomid from rooms table where allocated items are 0 and filter out room by building number = 1

tables structure is as below - ONLY ESSENTIAL FIELDS ARE SHOWN

```
rooms => roomid(PK), buildingblockID(FK), roomname
room_item => roomitemid(PK), roomid(FK), itemid(FK), quantity
item => itemid(PK), itemname
buildingblock => buildingblockid(PK), buildingID(FK)
building => buildingID(PK), buildingName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create derived table to find rooms having no items, and join it to buildingWiseRoom to filter building one.

```
select buildingWiseRoom.roomID
from buildingWiseRoom
inner join
(
   select RoomID
     from Room_Item 
    group by RoomID 
   having SUM(Quantity) = 0
) itemlessRooms
  on buildingWiseRoom.roomID = itemlessRooms.roomID
where buildingWiseRoom.buildingID = 1
```

**UPDATE as table structure changed:**

```
select rooms.roomID
from rooms
inner join buildingblock 
   on rooms.buildingblockID = buildingblock.buildingblockID
inner join
(
   select RoomID
     from Room_Item 
    group by RoomID 
   having SUM(Quantity) = 0
) itemlessRooms
  on rooms.roomID = itemlessRooms.roomID
where buildingblock.buildingID = 1
```

Comment: hi, @Nikola, I've Updated the table structure for better understanding with new added table, can u have a look at it ?